# Autoload routes as modules

Tags: vue.js, routes, vue-router, autoload

I've managed to create an autoloader for vuex store files, but I can't get it to work for vue-router files.

I always get the error `[vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration.`

index.js autoload file

```
import camelCase from 'lodash/camelCase';

const requireRoute = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/); // extract js files inside modules folder
const routes = {};

requireRoute.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  if (fileName === './index.js') return; // reject the index.js file

  const routeName = camelCase(fileName.replace(/(\.\/|\.js)/g, '')); //

  routes[routeName] = requireRoute(fileName).default;
});

export default routes;
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Home from '../views/Home.vue';

import routes from '@/routes/modules';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        icon: 'fa-tachometer',
        title: 'Dashboard',
        inMenu: true,
      },
    },
    routes,
  ],
});
```

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set `const routes = [];` and had to `.push()` it to the array.

So the following code works:

index.js

```
const requireRoute = require.context('.', false, /\.js$/); // extract js files inside modules folder
const routes = [];

requireRoute.keys().forEach((fileName) => {
  if (fileName === './index.js') return; // reject the index.js file

  routes.push(requireRoute(fileName).default);
});

export default routes;
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

import routes from '@/routes/modules';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) your `routes` **object**, so your main `routes` will contain not a **single object**, but a bunch of objects:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
    meta: {
      icon: 'fa-tachometer',
      title: 'Dashboard',
      inMenu: true,
    },
  },
  ...routes,
],
```

Comment: Just tried it. `Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`